# Does Apple AS assembler replace certain NEON instructions with equivalent ones on iOS?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, arm, neon

I was trying to use ffmpeg on iOS and was debugging a crash in the optimized arm code. I have discovered that some unsigned (.u16, .u32) instruction have been replaced by signed ones (.i16, .i32). It's easy to see because disassembled instruction on GDB doesn't quite match the source code.

For example,

```
vrshrn.u32 -> vrshrn.i32
vrshrn.u16 -> vrshrn.i16
vadd.u16 -> vadd.i16
```

My questions:

1. Is this behavior correct and expected? If not, how do we correct it?
2. If they are equivalent, why do we nee need the unsigned ones at all? Is it because that way the code is more explicit?
3. Is this behavior expected with other platform's toolkit? For example, Android's toolkit? (I have heard Apple's AS is an ancient one)

Answer (score 4):

These instructions don't depend on signedness of elements - that's actually what the `.Inn` suffix means. The assembler still accepts either `.Snn` or `.Unn` versions, but disassembly will only use `.Inn`.

For instructions which do differentiate between signed and unsigned integers (e.g. `VMULL`) the assembler won't accept the `.Inn` suffix, but only `.Snn` or `.Unn`.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same instruction.  The sign has no effect on the operation.

```
$ cat neon.s 
    .text
    .code 32
    .globl _foo
_foo:
    vrshrn.u32 d0, q0, #1
    vrshrn.i32 d0, q0, #1

$ otool -tv neon.o 
neon.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_foo:
00000000    f29f0850    vrshrn.i32  d0, q0, #1
00000004    f29f0850    vrshrn.i32  d0, q0, #1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can be assured that assemblers do nothing crazy, unlike some compilers.
When the assembler alters some instructions, it's mostly the exact equivalent or pseudo-insturction.